# Are there verbs for "undergo mitosis" and "undergo meiosis"?

Tags: cell-biology, meiosis, mitosis, terminology

From my experience on SE sites, I believe this is the right site to ask this question under "terminology".

I've been trying to find out whether English has one-word verbs for "undergo mitosis" and "undergo meiosis". I haven't been able to find confirmation on Google, but my linguistic imagination is limited, and I may have failed to google the right things.

Could you tell me if there are such verbs in common use in biology? I mean, if such verbs exist, can I find them in modern biology books or papers?

Comment: How about "divide" or even "multiply" (if you include the entire cell cycle)? Those are generic terms, but the process is called cell division. And minor pet peeve of mine: "Google" isn't a verb...

Comment: What's wrong with "to undergo mitosis"?

Comment: @nico Nothing is wrong with that. I just wanted to know if there's a shorter way of saying this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about linguistics rather than biology. There is no real problem. If you are writing a paper you would write "undergoes mitosis".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm actually not sure myself. If I were to use something, I would go with "Mitos'd" and "Meios'd".

However, you may not win over many fans, depending on the audience. If it's with students or maybe a professor, you could get away with shortening the processes. If it's in any formal setting, be as precise and descriptive as possible. It's not a lot of trouble to be more accurate and add "underwent" to the sentence.

Comment: I agree - I do not recall seeing a verb for these actions, so in a paper or report use the actual terminology. But during discussions I'm sure people will get your meaning if you shorten the terms to "mitose" or "mitosed", or something.

Answer (score 1):

Mitosis as a process does not have a verb form. However, as a process, there is an adjective; you could describe cells that undergo mitosis as mitotic.

Answer (score 0):

Wiktionary suggests `mitose`: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mitose.

Comment: The question asks “In common use in biology”, specifying books and papers. Wiktionary does not address that.

Answer (score -2):

Was just researching your exact same question.  Self-replicate is the closest I could find or think of... but it's a very general verb, not even biology specific.
e.g. Please don't self-replicate, I'm already having trouble with just one of you -- said the programmer to his memory gobbling AI program.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-replication